# Não consigo ignorar campos ao tentar retorná-los como Json causando "Infinite recursion"

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring, annotation

Estou trabalhando com *Hibernate*, *Spring* e *Jackson* (para ignorar os campos) e ao tentar retornar a classe **Usuario** em uma requisição json o java retorna erro devido ao mapeamento **@OneToMany** e **@ManyToOne** com a classe **Perfil**. Alguém sabe dizer o por quê ?

Ah, importante informar que estou tralhando com vários módulos geridos pelo **maven**, sendo eles:

```
|--marcenaria-dao

|--marcenaria-service

|--marcenaria-ws

|--marcenaria-web
```

Com isso, marcenaria-dao contem as beans (Usuario e Perfil) e é dependência do projeto marcenaria-service que por sua vez é dependência do webservice marcenaria-ws.

Abaixo a exception e as classes.

Usuario.java (marcenaria-dao)

```
package br.com.marcenaria.bean;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
public class Usuario extends BaseBean{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9146984943787732965L;

    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    private Perfil perfil;
    private Marcenaria marcenaria;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    @JsonManagedReference(value="perfil")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "perfil_id")
    public Perfil getPerfil() {
        return perfil;
    }
    public void setPerfil(Perfil perfil) {
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }
    @Column
    public Date getCriado() {
        return criado;
    }
    public void setCriado(Date criado) {
        this.criado = criado;
    }
    @Column
    public Date getInativo() {
        return inativo;
    }
    public void setInativo(Date inativo) {
        this.inativo = inativo;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="marcenaria_id")
    public Marcenaria getMarcenaria() {
        return marcenaria;
    }
    public void setMarcenaria(Marcenaria marcenaria) {
        this.marcenaria = marcenaria;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Perfil.java (marcenaria-dao)

```
package br.com.marcenaria.bean;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Perfil extends BaseBean{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6933398409318466304L;

    private String descricao;
    private List<Usuario> listaUsuario;

    public Perfil() {}

    public Perfil(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference(value="lista-usuario")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="perfil")
    public List<Usuario> getListaUsuario() {
        return listaUsuario;
    }
    public void setListaUsuario(List<Usuario> listaUsuario) {
        this.listaUsuario = listaUsuario;
    }
    @Column
    public Date getCriado() {
        return criado;
    }
    public void setCriado(Date criado) {
        this.criado = criado;
    }
    @Column
    public Date getInativo() {
        return inativo;
    }
    public void setInativo(Date inativo) {
        this.inativo = inativo;
    }
}
```

pom.xml (marcenaria-dao)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>marcenaria</groupId>
        <artifactId>marcenaria</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>marcenaria-dao</groupId>
    <artifactId>marcenaria-dao</artifactId>
    <name>marcenaria-dao</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

UsuarioController.java (marcenaria-ws)

```
package br.com.marcenaria.controller;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario;
import br.com.marcenaria.service.UsuarioService;
import br.com.marcenaria.view.Retorno;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Retorno<Usuario> login(@RequestBody final Usuario pUsuario)
        throws ServletException {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.acessar(pUsuario);

        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(usuario.getEmail())
                .claim("roles",Arrays.asList(usuario.getPerfil().getDescricao())).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();

        Retorno<Usuario> retorno = new Retorno<Usuario>();
        retorno.setObjeto(usuario);
        retorno.setToken(token);

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Exception

```
mar 11, 2016 2:30:15 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpMessageNotWritable
ADVERTÊNCIA: Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Usuario["perfil"]->br.com.marcenaria.bean.Perfil["listaUsuario"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem aqui um caso de recursão infinita devido ao relacionamento bi-direcional.

Digamos que *João* é um *Admin*:

- O objeto do tipo `Usuário` *João*, portanto, possuí uma referência para o `Perfil` *Admin*.
- O objeto `Perfil` em questão, por sua vez, possui uma lista de usuários, que inclui *João*.

Do lado do Java isso não é problema, as referências são apenas apontamentos para pedaços de memória.
Já na hora de escrever o `Usuário` *João* em JSON isso resultará em uma árvore infinita.

Eu percebi que você está tentando usar a anotação `@JsonIgnore` para tentar resolver o problema. Veja se você está usando [o pacote correto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895598/664577). Outras opções são "desmontar" (na falta de uma boa tradução técnica para o termo *detach*) o objeto do tipo `Perfil`e setar o valor de `listaUsuario`para `null`, ou ainda criar uma nova classe para a camada de *view* (E.g., Um `UserDto` onde perfil é uma `String`)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Anthony. Estou utilizando os pacotes corretos sim. Não quero utilizar DTOs e sim ignorar  os campos utilizando as annotations. Alterar o atributo listaUsuario com null funcionou, mas ainda deixarei a pergunta aberta para ver se alguém aponta o erro das annotations. Obrigado.

Comment: Opa, só por curiosidade, tente incluir uma dependência para o pacote [jackson-databind](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind), também vale a pena verificar se outras anotações no Jackson estão funcionando corretamente (oficialmente o Spring 4.2.5 só [foi testado](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html) com jackson 2.4, 2.5 e 2.6). Finalmente, escolha entre `@JsonManagedReference` / `@JsonBackReference`  ou `@JsonIgnore` (não os dois).

Comment: Adicionei a dependência mas sem resultado. Sobre o fato de utilizar o `@JsonIgnore` junto com o `@JsonBackReference` e o `@JsonManagedReference` foi uma das 7235 tentativas para resolver o problema, rsrs. Acredito que o problema esteja nos meus poms, acredito que WS não esteja utilizando o jar atualizado do marcenaria-dao. Vou investigar nesse sentido.

Answer (score -2):

Sei que o post é antigo, cheguei até aqui com o mesmo problema. A solução que encontrei foi utilizar as seguintes anotações:

```
    @Entity
    public class Agenda {
        
        @Id()
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        
        @Valid
        @NotEmpty
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({"agenda"})
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agenda", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
        private List<ItemAgenda> itens = new ArrayList<ItemAgenda>();
}

@Entity
public class ItemAgenda {
    
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private Agenda agenda;
}
```